# Ajax inside onbeforeunload is not working the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, onbeforeunload

I have been trying to bind `beforeunload` event by calling the following script so that I can go to the specified URL through `AJAX`. The problem is that the `AJAX` is not working the first time as the URL does not get called when the first time I do the page refresh. The second time ajax works. This problem gets fixed when I set `async` to `false` but then the alert popup inside `success` doesn't show up. I need alert box to also show up in `success` block.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    // this method will be invoked when user leaves the page, via F5/refresh, Back button, Window close
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event){
          // invoke the servlet, to logout the user
      $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "LogoutController" ,
        success: function (data) {
          alert("You have been logged out");
        }

      });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Just to warn you, your method will also be called whenever the user navigates a link within your site. So your user will be logged out on every page they visit (if the AJAX call manages to have time to complete, which it may not, and -- of course -- if this code exists on every page). `beforeunload` triggers on **every** page deconstruction; not just the events you list in your comment. Trying to track a user leaving a site/page is notoriously difficult, and prone to many issues, hence the reason most sites rely on session timeouts for auto log outs.

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool I need to get it to work for Chrome only.

Comment: @Pebbl Good news is I am working on a single page application. There are no next/previous page. Going away from the current page will cause the logout anyway. Anything I can do now for my single page web app?

Comment: @user2918640 ~ ah, ok. Still will be an odd behaviour if the user refreshes the page, but as you like :) -- you can do what you are doing, make sure the request is sync (async won't cut it, as you have found out). But there is no g'tee the browser will alert, as by this time the page will be deconstructing (& will have only been halted by the sync request). Better to leave "logging out" to the user, with a "log out" button. You could set a cookie message to display (if they land on a page you control). Either that or take a look at [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets)

Answer (score 1):

`beforeunload` will wait for the event handler to finish its execution before closing the page. Since an ajax call is asynchronous `beforeunload` is not going to wait for it to finish (your server however should still get the request). This is the expected behaviour and I don't think they is a way around it.

This behaviour can be reproduces using the following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    console.log("bye");
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("bye1");
    }, 200);
    console.log("bye2")
};

//bye
//bye2
```

Also, you should note that, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) the specs states that alert() can be ignored:

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event.

When this happens on chrome (only browser I checked) you will get the following message in the console:

```
Blocked alert('test') during beforeunload.
```

Comment: I can use async to false but in that case why the alert box inside the success block is not popping up? Or how do I wait till the the controller call finishes?

Comment: setting async to false will make onbeforeunload wait for the controller call to finish, but your alert might still be ignored by the browser.